# Mark test as skipped during test execution

Tags: testing, pytest

I have a test which depends upon a fixture named `fixture`.  This is roughly its code:

```
def test_optional_cool_feature(fixture):
    if not fixture.supports_cool_feature():
        return
    assert cool_feature() == expected_result
```

Here `fixture` is a parametrized fixture which exists in N variants and declared as

```
@py.test.fixture(scope="session", params=["type1", ...])
def fixture(request):
   if request.param = "type1":
       return Type1()
   elif ...
```

But it would also be nice to see the test as skipped (not as `PASSED`) in the `py.test` output when it is ran against a fixture which does not support `cool_feature`.  Unfortunately, this is not achievable with `@py.test.mark.skipif('not fixture.supports_cool_feature()')` because `fixture` is still a function at the time of execution of `skipif`, not a substituted test parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to my own question because I have missed the part of [documentation](http://pytest.readthedocs.org/en/2.1.0/skipping.html) on `skip` which says how to do exactly what I want:

> imperative skip from within a test or setup function
>
> If for some reason you cannot declare skip-conditions you can also
>   imperatively produce a skip-outcome from within test or setup code.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> def test_function():
>     if not valid_config():
>         pytest.skip("unsupported configuration")
> ```